# fetch data of childitem of exapndablelistview onClick event of checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

In my application i have an expandablelistview with checkbox in childlist.
All data of expandablelist view are fetched from webservice.

Now i want to fetch data of particular child raw which checkbox is selected.and also i have to perform multiple selection operation.
I want, when the checkbox is clicked, data of selected raw is stored in array.

here is my adapter class:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ServiceChildList child = (ServiceChildList) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
        }
        TextView one = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Subservicename);
        one.setText(child.getvName().toString());

        TextView two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Subservicetime);
        two.setText(child.getvDuration().toString());

        TextView three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Subserviceprice);
        three.setText("$" +child.getfPrice().toString()+".00");

        TextView four= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Subserviceid);
        four.setText(child.getiSubServiceId().toString());

        CheckBox check=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_check);

        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) buttonView ;
                ServiceChildList cList = (ServiceChildList) cb.getTag();
                cList.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );

            }
        });
        check.setTag( child );
        // Display planet data
        check.setChecked( child.isChecked() );

        return convertView;

    }
```

this is my activity class:

```
ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
            {

                ArrayList<ServiceChildList> ch_list = ExpListItems.get(groupPosition).getSub();

                int len = ExpandList.getChildCount();
                SparseBooleanArray checked = ExpandList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    if (checked.get(i)) {
                        String item = cont_list.get(i);
  /* do whatever you want with the checked item */
                    }


                String child_name = ch_list.get(childPosition).getvName();
                Log.d("dsijirji",child_name);
                String child_id = ch_list.get(childPosition).getiSubServiceId();
                Log.d("dsijirji",child_id);

                showToastMsg( child_id+"\n" + child_name);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), child_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Tell me where i made mistake. Help me for this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this example Hope it will helpful for you http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-use-expandablelistview-using.html